# Is it normal for a travel agency to ask for a photocopy of my credit card?

Tags: credit-card, payment, travel

I'm currently trying to get cheap plane tickets for a complex trip with a lot of stops, the only way to get the flight with one payment is to go to a travel agency. I'm doing this through a third (that I trust) in another country who found the right agency. The agency can offer me the flight, but they are asking for either a transfer or credit card in the next two days. I cannot do the transfer due to other reasons, so I intend to do it by credit card. The problem with the credit card option is that they are asking for a photocopy of both sides of the card and a photo of the passport.

Is asking for a photocopy of both sides of the card standard? Is this even legal?

Comment: What country are you in. What country is the travel agency

Comment: it's "legal", but very dubious.  it COULD BE a straightforward, over the top, security precaution.  (think of it as the next step after merely asking to see your ID.)

Comment: It’s no more or less secure than giving them the numbers over the phone.  And it doesn’t Rice’s to them that you have a real cans and not just a bunch of stolen numbers.

Comment: It could also be something as simple as they want to make sure you have the card in your possession, aka, you are not using a stolen card, but technically you could have stolen it and still have it in your possession but at least they can verify the name on it. So later when it is disputed or charged back, they can say, look we took precautions and all looked good, we are not giving it back. Think of it as giving them the card in person and/or providing the CCV on the back, that's what they are asking plus your ID information. You do it when you rent a car, why is it any weirder here?

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ I guess my problem is about trusting the agency. If a given agency gets my credit card info, it may start using it for other expenses in the future.

Comment: That is unfortunately a whole different animal. You just have to research them, ask around, find reviews and check their reputation and make a judgement call. But in technical terms, what they are asking for, especially for a remote, "I don't even see you" transaction, is not completely outside the realm of reasonable given they need to protect themselves as well.

Comment: Worst case scenario, if your card gets abused, you dispute it, they issue you a new card, you move on with your life. Your name, and passport, ok that could be a bit more touchy if gets abused. One of the reasons we always suggest dealing with credit is the fact that protections exist to quickly mitigate your damage, but the rest of it, I agree is a crap shoot.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ Thanks I think the whole trust issue is hard for me to grasp. I mean with the increasing number of web tools, it should be possible for every agency to make some unmanned internet transaction where they don't store your number as a photo in a sheet of paper or worst some pdf file in a computer.

Comment: Trust is a give and take, if you don't feel comfortable, imagine yourself in their shoes, why should they? Ultimately, you have to make a call on your own, nothing more I can add to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no laws against it and, albeit not a standard practice, it's not that uncommon, especially in the hospitality industry.
Another favourite one is getting the number via phone.

Sadly, it's up to the agency to decide how to store this information securely.

Comment: It is not an hotel is a travel agency to buy a plane ticket

Comment: yup, my bad, edited

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXU5VT8NJkM related video on PCI compliance when taking credit cards over the phone

Comment: how do you know a particular agency is following those security mechanisms?

Comment: You don't, in the same way you can't know if a website you're submitting your credit card details to, has the right level of PCI compliancy.

It's up to Visa and Mastercard to decide when businesses didn't comply and fine them. This doesn't work very well, as they usually fine businesses only after they've been breached.

On the good side, if someone steal your credit card details, banks are generally asking you a few questions to determine if you follow security practices and then refund you.